# Регулярное выражение для формата ip:port@login:password

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте. Есть проблема, нужно создать регулярное выражения для распаршивания данных вида:

> ip:port@login:password

Пример:

> 127.0.0.1:21@admin:82jrjxm

Пока не могу найти точное решение для данной проблемы. Получается, всё же нужно будет 4 типа регулярных выражения:

- Для поиска IP
- Для поиска порта
- Для поиска логина
- Для поиска пароля

Верно? Для IP пока есть идея шаблона, но по остальном даже не знаю.

P.S. В поисковых системах не нашел информации по подобному формату.

Comment: какая задача стоит? всмысле почему регулярка, возможно вам что то иное подойдет

Comment: Нужна ли проверка валидности IP и порта, входящих в исходную строку? Например: 999.999.999.999:3232323@xxxx:nnnn – должно распарситься? Или должно вернуть ошибку?

Comment: @Bookin, распарсить список прокси, которые заливаются в input, и добавить их в базу данных.

Comment: @rugabarbo, по-сути, валидность не нужна. Будут заранее подготовленные, валидные прокси попадать.

Comment: @Felix ну вон вам накидали примеров как достать данные из строки, выбирайте любой и пользуйтесь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Примеры](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/86a28bbf842848587003f18b52011554b6a4e8eb)

```
$text = '127.0.0.1:21@admin:82jrjxm';

$matches = preg_split('/[\:\@]/u', $text);
var_dump($matches);

preg_match('/^(.*):(.*)\@(.*?):(.*)$/', $text, $matches);
var_dump($matches);


preg_match('/^((?:\d{1,3}\.?)+)\:(\d{1,4})\@(\w+)\:([\d\w]+)$/', $text, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Все будет зависить от того что вам нужно в итоге.

Comment: В первых двух вариантах будет плохо, если в пароле есть двоеточие.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну собствено на то и пример, за истину не выдаю, нет условий нет решения, тут уж под задачу допилить

Comment: вообще будет плохо (хоть в маем хоть в вашем варинте) если какой либо из частей просто нет))

Comment: Ну с регулярками если части нет, всегда можно окружить в `(?:...)?`. А так, да, согласен, услоний нет)

Answer (score 2):

Неясно, конечно, какие части в вашей строке могут присутствовать, а какие нет. Но я бы копал не в сторону регулярок, а в сторону более простого варианта:

```php
$example = '127.0.0.1:21@admin:82jrjxm';
list($connectInfo, $userInfo) = explode('@', $example);
$asUrl = "http://$userInfo@$connectInfo";
$parts = parse_url($asUrl);
var_dump($parts);
```

Результат:

```
array (size=5)
  'scheme' => string 'http' (length=4)
  'host' => string '127.0.0.1' (length=9)
  'port' => int 21
  'user' => string 'admin' (length=5)
  'pass' => string '82jrjxm' (length=7)
```

Если же каких-то частей может не быть в строке, то нужно наличие собаки проверять перед `explode`.

Comment: Что может быть проще регулярок? о_О

Answer (score 1):

```
^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+):(\d+)@([^:]+):(.+)$
```

```js
var s = "127.0.0.1:21@admin:82jrjxm"
console.log(s.match(/^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+):(\d+)@([^:]+):(.+)$/))
```

Comment: Если порт будет > 65535, такая регулярка его пропустит... Невалидные IP тоже пропустит, но мой вариант с parse_url тоже этим страдает. Да и неясно, нужна ли автору проверка на валидность каждой из частей?

Comment: @rugabarbo, ну так просили распарсить, а не провалидировать :)

Comment: согласен. Это просто для размышления нам с Вами :)